# IIS Express 8.0 rewrite <rules> inside <outboundRules> not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis, url-rewriting

VS2010 IIS Express 8.0, trying to test rewrite rules in my development machine. I am adding this section to my web.config. Everything works until I add the 'rule' part inside the 'outboundRules' section, in which case I get the 500.52 error. I've tried all combinations or installing / uninstalling IIS, Windows Process Activation and all that, but nothing. Any ideas?

```
 <system.webServer>    
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to RewriteTest.aspx">
        <match url="^RewriteTest/([0-9]+)/(g[_0-9a-z-]+)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="RewriteTest.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <outboundRules>         
      <rule name="Rewrite to clean URL" preCondition="IsHTML">
          <match filterByTags="A" pattern="^/RewriteTest\.aspx\?id=([0-9]+)(?:&amp;|&amp;amp;)title=([_0-9a-z-]+)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="/RewriteTest/{R:1}/{R:2}" />
      </rule>
      <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsHTML">
          <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
      </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>        
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. IIS Express doesn't support outbound rules, then? I can't find anything about support for this by googling ...